# The loop in Python does not update the array, why?

Tags: python, numpy

The following code does not update the array V. The array is first created before the loop and is supposed to be changed within the loop, but it does not. Could someone explain why?

PS: I'm a beginner in Python.

```
import numpy as np
def priceCall(S0=4,u=2,d=0.5,T=1,r=0.25,K=5):
    n = range(T+1);
    Tmn = np.subtract(T,n);
    S = S0*np.power(u,Tmn)*np.power(d,n);
    p = (1+r-d)/(u-d);
    V = np.maximum(np.subtract(S,K),[0]*len(S));
    for j in range(1,T+1):
        for i in range(1,len(V)-j):
            V[i] = 1/(1+r)*(p*V[i]+(1-p)*V[i+1]);
    print(V)        
    return V
```

Comment: You should give us the actual output and your debugging trace.  I'm pretty sure that a couple of basic `print` statements will answer your question without our intervention.  See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your second forloop is not even executing. Let's assume you want to call `priceCall` with no parameters, in that case it means that the first range will be `range(1, 2)` which essentially means `[1]`, and `j=1` for the first iteration of the loop, meaning that the second range will be `range(1, 1)` which essentially means `[]` because the end index in a range will always be excluded.

Here is how I tested it:

```
import numpy as np

def priceCall(S0=4,u=2,d=0.5,T=1,r=0.25,K=5):
    n = range(T+1);
    Tmn = np.subtract(T,n);
    S = S0*np.power(u,Tmn)*np.power(d,n);
    p = (1+r-d)/(u-d);
    V = np.maximum(np.subtract(S,K),[0]*len(S));

    print("INITIAL")
    print(V)


    print("R1")
    print(range(1, T+1))
    for j in range(1, T+1):
        print("R2")
        print(range(1, len(V)-j))
        for i in range(1, len(V)-j):
            new_val = 1/(1+r)*(p*V[i]+(1-p)*V[i+1])
            print(new_val)
            V[i] = new_val

    print("AFTER")
    print(V)        
    return V

priceCall()
```

And here is the output:

```
(py3) > $ python sover.py                                                                                                                                                                                  
INITIAL
[3. 0.]
R1
range(1, 2)
R2
range(1, 1)
AFTER
[3. 0.]
```

Demonstration that the vector does indeed change:

```
import numpy as np

def priceCall(S0=4,u=2,d=0.5,T=1,r=0.25,K=5):
    n = range(T+1);
    Tmn = np.subtract(T,n);
    S = S0*np.power(u,Tmn)*np.power(d,n);
    V = np.maximum(np.subtract(S,K),[0]*len(S));

    print("INITIAL")
    print(V)

    V[0] = 9999

    print("AFTER")
    print(V)

priceCall()
```

with the output

```
(py3) > $ python sover.py                                                                                                                                                                                  
INITIAL
[3. 0.]
AFTER
[9999.    0.]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! However, according to your answer, there shouldn't be any problems if we set T=10. But this does not resolve the issue and the array is still not updated within the loop.

Comment: What you need to do is rethink your ranges, and what I'm assuming is that perhaps you need to add +1 to the end of the range, I don't know what this function is supposed to do but that's what I'm guessing the issue is.

Comment: Maybe if you can explain a bit what the code means and give the variables some meaningful names, while splitting the whole code into multiple lines usually helps anyone understand better what the purpose of the code is. The way your code currently is, is very unpractical and very unorthodox.

Comment: Again, even if you make non-empty ranges, the issue remains: V is not updated.

Comment: now that I don't believe. Do check my answer again with the updated simplified  demonstration that it indeed changes.

Comment: Could you please run the original code but with T=10? Why is it not updated?

Comment: I did, and it did change: 

`INITIAL
[4091. 1019.  251.   59.   11.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]

AFTER
[4.09100000e+03 1.65832294e+00 6.75676160e-01 2.22822400e-01
 4.50560000e-02 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00
 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]`

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out. I was looking at the first entry and forgot that indexing starts with 0.

Answer (score 0):

You have an off by one error in your nested for loop. len(V) is equal to 1 when you enter the first loop.